# Can't understand how does this return works

Tags: c++

can someone tell me how this **return** works or where I should search, I think it return's 2 values, but when i search i can't find nothing.

```cpp
BOOL __stdcall VirtualProtect()
{
char v1[4]; // [esp+4h] [ebp-4h] BYREF
String = 0;
lstrcatA(&String, "VertualBritect"); // No ragrets
byte_442581 = 'i';
byte_442587 = 'P';
byte_442589 = 'o';
pVirtualProtect = GetProcAddress(hKernel32, &String);
return (pVirtualProtect)(Shellcode, uBytes, 64, v1);
}
```

Comment: Without declarations and types it is hard to say but this looks like a function call (thru a pointer to a function).

Comment: I updated it...

Comment: The first set of parenthesis in that return statement is superfluous.  It's the same as `return pVirtualProtect(Shellcode, uBytes, 64, v1);`.  It's calling a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pVirtualProtect` is a function-pointer.   `GetProcAddress` is returning the address of a function, and that address is stored in the `pVirtualProtect` variable.

The return statement is calling (whatever function `pVirtualProtect` is pointing to) with the specified arguments (`Shellcode, uBytes, 64, v1`), and returning whatever value that function returned as a BOOL.